# How to isolate my program

Tags: c#, console, virtual-machine, sandbox

I'm working on a program that could actually delete all your system files.
so how can I sandbox it so it can only find its own files
or better can I put it in a kind of virtual machine environment, so it still can harm your system, but only the virtual.

it is a console application and the idea is that you have to develop it to be, a UI based machine and interact with other players / "machines"
although such contact may well also lead to major damage to your system.

i don't want the user to install a whole virtual machine and then execute the program, but this is the closest idea i got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think installing virtual machine is the only solution. If you are making the program able to delete all files in your system, it will be able to delete all files on your system. You are archiving exactly what you programmed, aren't you? So you just have to put it in Virtual machine or emulate environment for example by creating a folder on your drive and changing code of your application to have access only to this folder (walkaround...).

Comment: you are talking about permissions,
can you actually limit the program so much that it only can read/write to a single folder???
if yes how??

Comment: Well, if it is your program you can do whatever you want right? I don't know how your code looks like, so I can't help you with that. And I didn't talk about permisions. Just symulate that folder A is your main drive (instead of deleting files on main drive delete them in folder A....)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/):

> Sandboxie runs your programs in an isolated space which prevents them from making permanent changes to other programs and data in your computer.